# How to bypass payment step of checkout for testing purposes in Magento

Tags: magento

I've done some development work for an existing site, and I want to test the checkout process, but I can't get passed the payment step without actually paying. I want to bypass this for testing purposes. I'm using the onepage checkout

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: turn on pay by check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few payment methods in Magento by default that don't need to be "charged" during checkout - for example bank transfer, purchase order and check/money order.

You can enable them (if not enabled already) from admin via System -> Configuration -> Sales -> Payment Methods:

[image: Check/money order payment method]

Also, it sounds like your primary payment method doesn't have a sandbox account set up - ensure you do that, as you'll need to be able to test the integration with it outside of your production environment as well.